# CHROME CONSOLE MISSING ERROR NOTICES - Is this a feature or a flaw? Chrome Version 112.0.5615.137

Tags: google-chrome, console.log

- Pretty simple
- check out the captured behavior: https://www.screencast.com/t/KYupef2d0
- **Is that a feature or a flaw?**

**Summary:**

Google Chrome Console is "hiding" errors by nesting them in some new hidden obscure panel, but it sure seems like the console.log is broken because when clicking on the errors *"nothing shows up"*... It is painfully obvious to me that this has changed since I use the inspect element and console every day for about 8hr per day. This change is uncomfortable, illogical, inconvenient and in general has created a "bad ux"

this is now a bad user experience, which in turn has created unnecessary stress, resulting in constant cortisol release in my brain, reducing my productivity and limiting my ability to be effective at work. this... is illogical.

Maybe there is a way to change this in settings?